# Which is stronger: solid sockets, or two piece sockets?

Tags: tools

My jeep has a lot of torx bolts that I need to remove and then replace some of.  A while ago I bought a single torx socket from ACE hardware that is made from two steel pieces of metal.  The other day I got a set of torx bits from Autozone because I needed to use my reward zone points, the set I got from autozone are all singe pieces of metal that appear to be cast steel and don't feel too strong.

Which type of socket will hold up better when used with an impact driver?
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does the second socket made of two pieces that freely slide into each other, or are they fused solid?

Comment: They are fused together somehow.  I'm not sure how.

Comment: For whatever it might be worth, SnapOn make two-piece hex (and I assume Torx) sockets where the bit is secured in the "carrier" with an Allen screw (for which the kindly supply the wrench). Each carrier is a different size to fit the bit (which means in a pinch you could probably replace a damaged bit by cutting off the end of a conventional L-shaped Allen wrench. Craftsman makes similar sockets, but they use a standard sized hole in the bit carrier.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really matter as to if they're single or multi-piece, what's important is to get sockets that are designed for impact use.

Comment: I completely agree, and neither of the sockets above look like a proper impact socket to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with the "no brand" single piece units. They seem to be prone to catastrophic failure. As you are torquing the ratchet they fracture. The two piece units seem to flex slightly giving some indication that you are overloading it. Although they make a high quality impact driver compatable single piece unit, I doubt it is sold at Pep Boys, AutoZone ,Harbor Freight etc.A single quality impact socket can cost as much as set of the cheap units. When using impact tools a quality socket is important as a failure can release a lot of shrapnel.

Comment: The piece to the right in the photo cost as much as a set of 5 of the ones from Autozne, but ACE has expensive sockets.  I try to get mine online.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use the single bit when working with an impact driver. For such applications, the bit should be firmly secured in the sleeve and I'd be uncomfortable having somewhat loose pieces attached to my tool.

Torx heads provide very good contact between the screw and the head which minimizes tool wear, and cam-out is pretty much impossible, so your cheap-feeling bit should work okay even at moderate loads, especially for small screw sizes.